# C# ProcessStartInfo: how to specify filepath?

Tags: c#, process

I can see that in ProcessStartInfo you can specify a file name, but how do you specify a file path?

Thanks.

Comment: Just specify the full path (including the filename) as the file name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When it says "filename" it means full or relative path to the file. So you could do something like `@"C:\program files\my folder\myProcess.exe";` for example. Or `@".\..\..\MyRelativePathedProcess.exe";` You can also control the CWD with Process.StartInfo's WorkingDirectory property.

Answer (score 4):

use `Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory`
or just specify the full path of the file name.