# C# Starting a program from another program

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have this method

```
private void StartSDCBackupSet() {
    using (Process p = new Process()) {
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "SDCBackup";
        try { 
            p.Start(); 
            BackIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Backup", "Editor for settings startet", ToolTipIcon.Info); 
        } catch (Exception) { 
            MessageBox.Show("Program til settings blev ikke fundet"); 
        }
    }
}
```

According to the documentation I can find - and quite a lot of answers here -, it should start another program - SDCBackup.exe.

It doesn't. And I HAVE tried adding the .exe to the filename, but it does not make a difference. I get the messagebox with the message...
I have checked `p` and `StartInfo` and everything looks right. `StartInfo.UseShellExecute` is true.

Debugging reveals, that it is the line `p.Start();` that produces the exception. And the Exception is a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` with message:

> File not found

Documentation says, that the code above does the excat same thing as `Run` in Windows menu, but it obviously does not.

If I write `SDCBackup` in the RUN section of Windows menu, SDCBackup.exe is started as it should.
(And SDCBackup.exe is a ClickOnce installation, that nobody really knows where to find - other than Windows itself...)

**So why does my code not do the trick?**

Comment: `.FileName` refers to either the full path to the executable or a relative path, please see this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054904/c-sharp-processstartinfo-how-to-specify-filepath)

Comment: Your code worked for me. I placed an exe file in the debug folder of my project and when execution hit p.Start() the program ran. SDCBackup has to be in bin\debug unless you specify a full path.

Comment: Relying on the value of Environment.CurrentDirectory is forever wrong.  Might not be wrong today, will be wrong on a rainy day.  It is the worst possible global variable you can imagine.  Always use the full path name c:\foo\bar\file.ext.  Where necessary (usually), use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location to find out where your program ended up getting deployed.  In a Winforms app you can use Application.StartupPath.

Comment: There's no `RUN section` in the Windows Menu. You probably confused it with Search.

Comment: @rich If I put in calc.exe f.ex., it works just fine. But apparently not with my own program - but if I type SDCBackup in Search in Windows Menu, my program is run.

Comment: @Pangiotis: From learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/…: "The StartInfo members can be used to duplicate the functionality of the Run dialog box of the Windows Start menu."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems no one knows how to reference a ClickOnce installed application in another application. (Asked the question at Microsoft, and got no useful response there either.)

It seems ClickOnce apps are installed somewhere in the current users area, e.g.:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0
```

and from there 3 randomly named folders down - and not the same folder names for different users; so there seem to be no way to solve this.

But I did get a way to create a regular installer from Microsoft, for Visual Studio C# solutions.

I used it to set the install path of my apps, so they can find it each other - and it functions.

- Install [projecttype Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)
- and follow the [explanation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b7d094a-68d3-4477-8710-1de2f3ace8f0/starting-one-app-from-another?forum=csharpgeneral)

It involves adding a Installer project to the solution.

I found, that in addition to the explanation,

- you have to go to **Options** for the installer-project,
- select **"Configuration Manager",
- and set it to be included when building

I also found, that version control is not automatic. You must manually set version number - and for the sake of simplicity, this is a different format than the one Visual Studio uses. If you do set the version, it will automatically uninstall previous versions of the same app.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include the hint the application you're looking for is a Click Once installation. I don't see that in the question right now. You might also want to add the `clickonce` tag so that experts on that technology see the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SDCBackup.exe";
```

Windows tests out known file types, and if it's an .exe (or any other known type, such as .bat, msc, scr, etc.) it runs it. As far as I know .NET does not do that.

You could try using `Path.GetFullPath` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx) but I think it should work with relative paths as well.

Also make sure the file is inside your debug/release folder (whatever folder your .exe that is starting SDCBackup is in), since Windows looks in known directories that are contained in the `PATH` variable (such as `C:\windows\System32`, etc), and .NET does not. If it is not in that folder, provide a fully qualified path and it should work.

Comment: Windows *doesn't* assume.  If the executable is in the local folder or accessible through the `PATH`, it will run. If it's not, it won't.

Comment: Windows does *not* look into known directories either, it looks into the directories specified in the PATH environment vairalbe. .NET does the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are absolutely right. Is this adressed with my edit?

Comment: Because it's wrong. Adding the extension won't help. Windows and .NET use the same logic, the same *Windows* functions to look for an executable - either absolute location, relative location or PATH

Comment: Why does it function in Windows, and not in my code, then, if they do the same?
Win 7, Start - there is a line at the bottom. I type my programs name, and it is RUN.
Call it what you like.
Windows finds the program, .NET does not.
Qestion was why?

Comment: The SDCBackup is a ClickOnce installation. Maybe someone knows where it is - I do not.
Using WindowsExplorer, searching for SDCBackup or SDCBackup.exe, gives no results...

Comment: @BirgerSørensen well there's a difference between the `RUN` field and what you use. Press `Win+R`, and then type SDCBackup.exe. It will not run I assume. It seems like what you've been using is the start menu, not the `RUN` field.